# LINQ to a model including List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I would like to get your advice on Linq.

I have 3 tables users ( listing all the users), another one userEtablishments (one user can have many places), and the table Establishment (to list the place)

i have a models which is:

```
public class UserVM {
 public Int32 id { get; set; }
 public string name { get; set; }
 public List<Etablishment> Etablishments { get; set; }
}
```

and the Etablishment:

```
public class EtablishmentVM {
 public Int32 id { get; set; }
 public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I query first the users, then establishments of the user, but its very slow:

```
UserVM obj = new UserVM();
using (context db = new context(ConnectionString))
{
 userlist = (from u in db.users
  join p in db.establishments on u.id equals p.id
  join pe in db.userEtablishments on p.id equals pe.id
   select new
    {
      u,
    }).FirstOrDefault();
    if (entity != null)
    {
      obj.id = entity.u.id);
      obj.name = entity.u.name);
      // Then get the establishment list then update the establishmentVM
      List<EstablishmentVM> userplaces = new List<EstablishmentVM>();
      var userplacesList = (from u in db.users join p in db.establishments on 
        u.id equals p.id join pe in db.userEtablishments on p.id equals pe.id 
        select new { u, pe }).ToList();
        if (userplacesList  != null && userplacesList.Count > 0)
        {
          foreach (var item in userplacesList)
          { }.....
```

is there a better way to do to get it execute faster ?

Any advices would helps, the purpose is to get betterperformances.

Thanks for your helps

Comment: You probably mena Linq?

Comment: Linq, and refactor, and....a few things...that was hard to read.  Strongly recommend google translate if English isn't your first language.  Also, what are you actually doing with the items in `userplaceslist`?  `Parrallel.ForEach' might be your performance fix.

Comment: Hi, i reformule the question, hope its easier to understand now

Comment: Hi Nemanja, yes Linq

Comment: Hi CDove the userplaceslist isused in a foreach loop to populate the EstablishmentVM

Comment: Shouldn't have to do 2 queries - that's the purpose of navigation properties: `select usersWithEstablishments = db.Users.Include(u => u.Establishments).ToList();` Then you could use a tool like automapper to `.Project().To<UserVM>`.

Comment: What do you want to do in the end ? Populate establishments into user class ? Populate everything from database ?

Comment: Hi Aboc, yes populate the UserVM class with all informations from database

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or NHibernate ?

Comment: aboc -> Entity Framework

Comment: Hi Steve, in u => u.Establishments: VS doesn' t recognise and gives autocomplete on Establishments of u.Establishments

Comment: Why don't you just map everything using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx/ "code first" or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx "database first" ?

Comment: aboc: i am using code first actually, db.users for example is a code first class, the problem is how to query of the database get best performances